# C# - property assignment event in attribute

Tags: c#, events, attributes, poco, universal

How can I make a simple attribute, that I can use anywhere with any POCO class.
That attribute should receive an event when the property is changed.

E.g. universal string length limiter.

```
class MyPoco{
  [MyLengthLimiter(11)]
  public string MyLimitedString{get;set;}
}
```

Then, wherever or whenever the MyLimitedString gets assigned, my custom attribute gets triggers.

Comment: This is not possible directly. On way could be to emit the necessary code at compilation time using Fody: https://github.com/Fody/Fody

Comment: Check [Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged using PostSharp](http://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-add)